# how can i unserialize a data from database and view it in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

how can i convert Serialized string into text?

```
public function create()
{
    $orders=new Order();
    $orders->transform(function($order,$key){
           $orders= unserialize ($orders->name);
           return toArray ($order);
    });
    $data=$order->get();      
    return view('Admin.order')
            ->with('orders',$data);
    return view('Admin.order',['orders'=>$orders]);
}
```

Comment: _NOTE:_ Nothing after a `return` gets run. So the second `return` will never get executed

Answer (score 0):

After the return any line included will not be executed.

Comment: How can i simply serialize and unserialize a session data befre storing into a database?